# How to use the cordova plugin bluetoothle in ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

**Additional information:**

I know the usual  [way](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-in-ionic-2-with-ionic-native/) to access cordova plugins:

```
(<any>window).plugins.myPlugin 

or

declare var yourGloballyAccessablePlugin: any;
```

but it's different with the plugin [bluetoothle](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle) (the native bluetooth plugins supported by ionic 3 are not good enough as they do not provide bluetooth peripherial functionality e.g. advertising)

**Solution attempt:**

[I found a related question on the ionic forums and asked how they achieved this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-non-ionic-cordova-plugins-properly/109963/13), so far I faild to replicate the process and no one answered my question so far, thats why this question was opened.

Apparently bluetoothle exposes a globally accessible variable.

As stated there I added a `declaration.d.ts` file to my `src` folder
with the following content:

```
declare module 'cordova-plugin-bluetoothle';
import 'cordova-plugin-bluetoothle';
declare var cordova: any;
```

I then tried to access the plugin (tested it on my phone) like this:

```
import { bluetoothle } from 'cordova-plugin-bluetoothle';

...

(<any>window).bluetoothle
```

**Problem:**

But bluetoothle is always undefined for me. Since I'm new to cordova, ionic and TypeScript I guess that there is something wrong with the way I'm using declarations.d.ts

So does someone know what I'm doing wrong, **how can I use the cordova native plugin bluetoothle in ionic 3?**

**UPDATE, Solution attempt 2**:

So I tried to run this code within the initial project structures `app.component.ts` as recommended by @Webruster with the init params from the bluetoothle [documentation](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle):

(the only goal here is to see whether the plugin works)

imports...

```
declare var cordova: any;
```

@Component, class start and attributes...

```
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService, platform: Platform, settings: Settings, private config: Config, private statusBar: StatusBar, private splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      console.log("I'm ready");
      // your bluetothle methods can be accessed after
      //cordova.plugins.bluetoothle
      // for brevity i added a sample method from repo , it can be changed
      //based on your need
      let initializeResult: object;
      let params: object = {
        "request": true,
        "statusReceiver": false,
        "restoreKey": "bluetoothleplugin"
      };
      cordova.plugins.bluetoothle.initialize(initializeResult, params);

      console.log(JSON.stringify(initializeResult));

      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
    this.initTranslate();
  }
```

but this way the app does not even load, it just times out and outputs the connection to the server was unsuccessful when I run the app without the plugin code it works.

**UPDATE 2:**

I debugged the app with chrome (the previous error was caused by the --livereload option for an unkown reason) 
and this is the error I get:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined
```

checking the types of `cordova`, `cordova.plugins` and `cordova.plugins.bluetoothle`
with:

```
  console.log(typeof cordova);
  console.log(typeof cordova.plugins);
  console.log(typeof cordova.plugins.bluetoothle);
```

I get the following results:

```
object
object
undefined
```

Comment: To clarify, I do not necessarily need to port the application (which I developed for my student project) to smartphones but since I can reuse most of my code (because it's written with angular 5) this would be a nice to have extention

Comment: there are couple of questions , 1. where is ur initialization code for the ionic ? where are you calling this method ? in `app.component.ts` ?

Comment: I used the default starter app from Ionic 3 and tried to access the plugin as soon as the platform is ready e.g. injecting the Platform in the constructor and then accessing it in the constructor like this: this.platform.isReady().then((params) => { ... accessing plugin here }. Yes I mean the app.component.ts component.

Comment: Could someone tell me why my question is considered not useful or poorly researched?

Comment: dont mind about response .. +1 for updating the process attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install the plugin (ionic3):

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetoothle
```

Then use `(<any>window).bluetoothle` when the platform is ready to access the plugin insted of the usual location (cordova.plugins) based on @dinomight post on the [ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-non-ionic-cordova-plugins-properly/109963/12) :

> the window object seems to be loading the bluetoothle module. if i
>   console.log(window) i can see it right there with all of its
>   functions. problem is if i try to reference it via
>   “window.bluetoothle” i get a new error

**Here is the test code** (only the constructor because I did not modify anything else) which prompts you to activate bluetooth (only supported on android) and and activates it after allowing it to do so (the code is located in the `component.app.ts` of the extended ionic3 starter app):

```
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService, platform: Platform, settings: Settings, private config: Config, private statusBar: StatusBar, private splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

      let initializeResult: object;
      let params: object = {
        "request": true,
        "statusReceiver": false,
        "restoreKey": "bluetoothleplugin"
      };

      (<any>window).bluetoothle.initialize(initializeResult, params);

      let enableSuccess: object;
      let enableError: object;

      (<any>window).bluetoothle.enable(enableSuccess, enableError);

      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
    this.initTranslate();
  }
```

**Testenvironment:**

I tested this on Android 7.1.1 (lineageOS) on my Nexus 5

Comment: its the same as the one i defined , instead of cordova, you have defined the windows object with type any. any way glab it helped you

Comment: I know, i gave you the bounty since I got what I wanted

Answer (score 5):

Just like the normal way , you can install it with:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetoothle
```

after this  include below line after your imports statement as follows:

```
declare var cordova:any;
```

And use it when the platform is ready:

```
platform.ready().then(
    () => {
        console.log("I'm ready");
        // your bluetothle methods can be accessed after 
        //cordova.plugins.bluetoothle
        // for brevity i added a sample method from repo , it can be changed 
        //based on your need
        cordova.plugins.bluetoothle.initialize(initializeResult, params);
    }
);
```

Comment: did you test it ? I thought I tried that(as described in my comment under my question), I will test it later and report back.

Comment: @MADforFUNandHappy i usually run plugins like this which are not in ionic native , the one you implemented were using `MODULAR` model , so this is in a bit of javascript approach

Comment: I had to use ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetoothle since I'm using ionic3, I tried you example and added the init params but I just get an black screen when the app loads on my nexus 5 ... I will add the code to my question, maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: I try to debug it, didn't know that I could to this with chrome

Comment: @MADforFUNandHappy please check in the real devices , when you got the blank screen did you checked in the console?

Comment: @MADforFUNandHappy have you checked in real device?

Comment: Yes I'm testing on a real device, Nexus 5, I will try again later

Comment: @MADforFUNandHappy try to get the console log for it

Comment: I  award this answer the 50 reputation because it put me on the right track (together with the guy in the ionic forums). This stack meta question also seems to promote giving the bounty to a helpful answer (also my question might not have been clear enough) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267376/ethics-on-bounty-award-when-best-answer-only-solved-half-of-the-problem

Answer (score 1):

There is a wrapper for this plugin you can use here: https://github.com/somq/ionic-plugin-bluetoothle.

However, while this is a great way to use the plugin, it doesn't wrap all the methods and therefore didn't work for what I needed. If it has the methods you need then I recommend using it.

My main recommendation is to use 

`(<any>window).bluetoothle.{method name}`

as described by a previous poster. Of all the techniques described here, that is the only one that worked for me.

I hope that helps anyone reading this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the top of every page where you wish to use the plugin to get rid of IDE errors:

declare var bluetoothle: any;

Answer (score 0):

After more time working on this, I have found there are 4 ways to do this (improving on my earlier answer):

1. Use the plugin wrapper here if you don't need every plugin method wrapped (many are missing): https://github.com/somq/ionic-plugin-bluetoothle
2. Use `(<any>window).bluetoothle.{method name}({arguments});` anywhere in your code. This works great, but crashes Ionic View.
3. Use `declare var bluetoothle;` at the top of your file, and then you can get to the plugin via: `bluetoothle.{method name}({arguments});`. Works great, but also crashes Ionic View.
4. Copy the existing wrapper plugin, and add it to your own source code as a provider, then just wrap the remaining methods that you need to use. The file to copy is here: https://github.com/somq/ionic-plugin-bluetoothle/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/bluetooth-le/index.ts. A guide on how to wrap a plugin is here: http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20170908-WritingAnIonicNativeWrapper.html

4 is the cleanest solution if like me you need more methods wrapped than somq has completed in his project. This method will stop Ionic View from crashing, but turns out the plug-in isn't supported anyway, so you still can't use it in Ionic View.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: 
 We have to import this plugin

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial
npm install --save @ionic-native/bluetooth-serial
```

Step 2:
 Add ***BluetoothSerial*** inside the provider *app.module.ts* page
Step 3:
 Enable the bluetooth 
 Your mobile bluetooth automatically on or ask you permission.

```
      unpairedDevices: any;
      pairedDevices: any;
      gettingDevices: Boolean;
    constructor(private bluetoothSerial: BluetoothSerial,
     private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    bluetoothSerial.enable();
  }
```

step 4: start scanning

```
    startScanning() {
    this.pairedDevices = null;
    this.unpairedDevices = null;
    this.gettingDevices = true;
    this.bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired().then((success) => {
      this.unpairedDevices = success;
      console.log(success, "hai")
      this.gettingDevices = false;
      success.forEach(element => {
        // alert(element.name);
      });
    },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })

    this.bluetoothSerial.list().then((success) => {
      this.pairedDevices = success;
    },
      (err) => {

      })
  }
  success = (data) => alert(data);
  fail = (error) => alert(error);
```

> step 5: After detect available bluetooth device select any one of
>   those.

```
 selectDevice(address: any) {

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Connect',
      message: 'Do you want to connect with?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Connect',
          handler: () => {
            this.bluetoothSerial.connect(address).subscribe(this.success, this.fail);
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();

  }
```

step 6: Disconnect device

```
isconnect() {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Disconnect?',
  message: 'Do you want to Disconnect?',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Disconnect',
      handler: () => {
        this.bluetoothSerial.disconnect();
      }
    }
  ]
});
alert.present();
```

}

step 7: home.html page

```
    <ion-content padding>

 <ion-list padding>
  <button ion-button block (click)="startScanning()">scan</button>
  <ion-list-header>
    Paired Devices
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let device of pairedDevices">
    {{device.name}}
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button block (click)="disconnect()">Disconnect</button>
  <ion-list-header>
    availlable Devices
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-item *ngFor='let device of unpairedDevices'>
    <span (click)="selectDevice(device.address)">
      {{device.name}}
    </span>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-spinner name="crescent" *ngIf="gettingDevices"></ion-spinner>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Note: I hope it will you.
      Have a nice day!.

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding, I'm referring to the Cordova plugin bluetoothle which provides the possibility to use the Bluetooth adapter as central and peripheral. The Bluetooth plugin provided by ionic native does only support Bluetooth central functionality.

Comment: Take a look at the link of bluetoothle in my question, its another plugin which is not supported by ionic native and cant be used the usual way in which cordova plugins can be made accessible in ionic native.